# How do I migrate 50TB of Enterprise Vault to Exchange Online

Tags: email, migration

I have been asked to migrate 50Tb of Enterprise Vault Journals to Exchange Online.
Unfortunately I do not have experience in migration of emails. However I have experience in data migration.
So I was suggesting that -
Can we use Azure Data Factory to pump the journals to the Online Azure Database.
I had a look in the net but all of them are talking about uploading.PST file using AzCopy.
Any guidance is much appreciated.

I have looked around in the net to find the solution. Most of them talk about uploading the .PST file. However, the size of journal does not give me the confidence in uploading .PST file using AzCopy.